# Using knitr with GIS data

Tags: r, latex, gis, knitr

I'm attempting to create a presentation about loading/using shapefiles in R using the knitr package.  The issue I'm encountering is that when I include standard @ notation in my .Rnw file, as in `ND@data`, R reads that as the end of the code chunk meaning a bunch of my code doesn't get read in properly.

Here is a fuller example of my .Rnw file (data available from the North Dakota GIS portal http://www.nd.gov/gis/apps/HubExplorer/).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

<<Loading Datasets>>=

install.packages("rgdal")

library(rgdal)

ND <-readOGR(dsn="C:/Users/.../NDGISHubData", 

layer="NDHUB_STATE_polygon")

  head(ND@data)

  ND@proj4string

  plot(ND)

@

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to have R correctly recognize the @ symbol in my code chunk as part of the code and not as the end of the R code chunk?

Comment: I did `knitr::knit2pdf()` on your example (after setting `eval=FALSE` in the chunk header, like so: `<<Loading Datasets, eval=FALSE>>=`) and it works just fine, as I'd've expected it to.

Comment: This does show the code but doesn't show R's output, which I would like to show.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. I only set `eval=FALSE` because I didn't want to download and run with your data. `knitr` should in general have no problem handling ampersands, and only interprets them as ending a code chunk when they appear as the first character on a line. I suspect/am nearly certain that something else about your data or document is causing whatever problem you're experiencing.

Comment: That's strange.  I'm editing my .Rnw in TeXStudio and it shows the chunk beginning/ending bits in a light blue.  I can see that that @ symbol in ND@data is highlighted in light blue.  When I set eval=FALSE the code is printed as you would expect, no errors.  But when I run with eval=TRUE R throws the error: Quitting from lines 38-56 (GIS in R.Rnw)  (Which corresponds to the code I shared above).  Any ideas what might cause that?  If I run my R code in the R console it runs just fine.

Comment: Okay I seem to have fixed this problem simply by closing both LaTeX and R and restarting them.  I'm not sure why that made a difference but now the code runs without errors.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't use the @ symbol in user code. Use as.data.frame(ND) and proj4string(ND)